# Resize images via drag and drop on OSX with good quality

Tags: macos, osx-lion, images, adobe-photoshop, automator

I want to be able to drag and drop images on an application(icon) which preferably doesn't run. This application has to resize the images to 600x450px and drop them somewhere.

I already created an Automator action which does exactly that but the quality is less then stellar compared to having it resized via the Preview-function or Photoshop. Below you can find an example pictures resized in Automator and Photoshop.

While there are Photoshop Automator Actions http://www.robotphotoshop.com/?page_id=8 they aren't compatible with Photoshop CS6 yet.

So for now I'm looking for something else which does the job with good quality and compression.

**Automator resized picture**
[image: Automator resized picture]

**Photoshop resized picture**
[image: Photoshop resized picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use ImageMagick in an Automator application:

[image]

`/usr/local/bin/mogrify -filter Lanczos2 -resize 500x -format jpg -quality 96 -path ~/Desktop/ "$@"`

The default filter for downscaling images is `Triangle`, which often makes images look too blurry without additional sharpening in my opinion. `Triangle` is similar to the resizing methods used by Automator and `sips`. I usually use `Lanczos2` (2-lobe Lanczos), which makes images less sharp than `Lanczos` (`Lanczos3` or 3-lobe Lanczos). `Lanczos2` is almost identical to `Catrom`, and it is also similar to the bicubic option in Photoshop.

You can add sharpening with something like `-sharpen 0x0.4+0.8`. `0` sets an automatic radius for the convolution kernel, `0.4` is the radius, and `0.8` is the amount.

You can compare the different filters with a command like this:

`for f in Bartlett Blackman Bohman Box Catrom Gaussian Hanning Hermite Lagrange Lanczos Lanczos2 Mitchell Parzen Point Robidoux Sinc Spline Triangle Welsh; do convert -filter $f -resize 50% input.png $f.png; done`

I uploaded a comparison of different resizing options at http://lri.me/upload/imagemagick-osx-resizing/.

Documentation:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/
- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that. Sorry. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 1):

[Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) supports Automator, but I do not know the quality of the results.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TurboTool](http://www.tinbert.com/TurboTool/manual/qe-image-resize.html) for just another way to create a Drag&Drop solution from a command line program with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

On the website you'll find a **Quick Example** to resize an image.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I develop a [batch image resizing tool called ImageXY](http://www.imagexyapp.com) that will do just this. Drag-drop images from the Finder or direct from iPhoto onto the icon and it will resize them according to a preset. You can set the resize quality so you can go for quality or smaller file sizes.